# Access claim value in azure b2c custom content page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How can access claim value from a previously populated claim in a custom html page?

I have tried specifying a claim as a `<UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>` and then marking it as an output claim of my `TechnicalProfile` that uses the custom html pahe like so

`<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="labsobject" />`

This makes the readonly input show up but the value that shows in the box is  `labsobject` as opposed to the actual value of the claim. Accessing the value through JS also shows an empty string.

I confirmed the claim has value as it is later correctly embedded into the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prepopulate claims on a selfAsserted technical profile, add them first as an input claim, then as an output claim to display on the screen.